# employee hierarchy query in sqlite without using "WITH" clause

Tags: sqlite

Can anyone please help me to get employee hierarchy without using "WITH' in sqlite. Why because "WITH" is not supporting in SQLite 3.7.17 version.

Comment: please add your database schema and a query of what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_with.html#recursivecte) explains how recursive CTEs work.

You have to do these steps manually in your code.